# how to inherit the _constraints on odoo v8?

Tags: inheritance, constraints, odoo-8, odoo

As for _sql_constraints work :

```
def _auto_init(self, cr, context=None):
    self._sql_constraints = [
            ('planned_field_uniq', 'unique(field1,field2,)', 'Already exist'),
    ]
    super(object_name, self)._auto_init(cr, context)
```

couldn't figure it out for `_constraints` I tried also the

```
@api.constraints('field1','field2')
def _check_duplicate_(self):
    _logger.info('MY CONSTRAINT IS CALLED')
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Do you want to remove it or update it !!

Comment: add or update it

Answer (score 3):

In python you can monkey patch any thing you can try thid technique hope it work

Import the class that you want to alter it's constraints attribute.

```
       from openerp.addons.addon_name....class_name

       class_name._constraints  = new_value
```

This code is executed before Odoo builds the global Model class from the list of classes. This way when odoo start checking constraints this value will be changed because that value is always retreived from that class.

Because it's not sql_constrains this should work, you are changing it in runtime.